# ¿Cómo detectar el navegador de la aplicación Facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, programación-móvil, navegador-web

Necesito saber si están navegando en mi pagina web desde el navegador que trae la aplicación Facebook desde un dispositivo móvil.

He conseguido este codigo pero solo funciona en iOS, pero no en Android.

```
var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
    userAgent  = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    safari     = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
    ios        = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

if( ios ) {
    if ( !standalone && safari ) {
        // Browser
    } else if ( standalone && !safari ) {
        // Standalone
    } else if ( !standalone && !safari ) {
        // UI Web View (Facebook in-app browser)

    };
} else {
    // Not iOS
};
```

Comment: No deberías forzar el uso de un navegador en particular o externo al del propio FB. Deberías respetar la decisión del usuario que ha configurado en su FB (o la opción por defecto si es el caso) que se abran los enlaces en el navegador interno o cambiar las opciones de FB para abrir el enlace externamente.

Comment: Tienes razón @Carlos Muñoz, muchas gracias. Pero como detecto si es el navegador de Facebook?